# Selenium Webdriver - How to deal with the html page Element/Count after delete

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to fix the problem i am facing, but i ran out of ideas so I need help here.

I have a very simple page:

```
╔════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════╗
║          RoleName          ║                Delete                 ║
╠════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════╣
║ ABC1 (index starts with 1) ║ [delete button] (index starts with 0) ║
║ ABC2                       ║ [delete button]                       ║
║ ABC3                       ║ [delete button]                       ║
║ ABC4                       ║ [delete button]                       ║
║ ABC5                       ║ [delete button]                       ║
╚════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════╝
```

And here is the code that automates it:

```java
//count how many rows avaiable
IList<IWebElement> count = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div#ctl00_MainContent_divUserInfo"));

//note: starting with 1 since the RoleName colum starts with 1 (html code render on the page)
for (int i = 1; i <= count.Count; i++)
{

    string selName = string.Empty;
    selName = String.Format("div#ctl00_MainContent_divUserInfo tr.item:nth-of-type({0}) > td a#aDetail:nth-child(1)", i);

    string selNameText = TextByCssSelector(selName);
    bool isNameExists = Names.Any(s => selNameText.Equals(s.Value.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

    if (isNameExists)
    {
        //if found then click on delete button to remove the item....
    }

}
```

The above code is working as I expect to be but there is a problem and the problem is that if I delete the row than following things happens:

1. Page get re-render the page again
2. I get a new set of count

But remember I'm still in the `for-loop`, so my count is based on previous (before i delete the row) my question is:

How should I deal with this type of situation?

Comment: How about using an index for your current location and don't increase it if you delete the role. When your index is past the last item, you're done. So, do it all in something like `while (index < driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div#ctl00_MainContent_divUserInfo").Count) { ... }`

Comment: i dont think you can use `driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div#ctl00_MainContent_divUserInfo").Count`

Comment: what is index here? i am confused.... will you post your logic if you think it  will work?

Comment: @WaleryStrauch: looks like your logic worked... i will let you know later after i test more and you can post your answer as answer below and i will accept that as an answer.

Comment: Your post is not very clear about the end goal. What are your trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run your loop in reverse order:

```
for (int i = count.Count; i > 0; i--) { ... }
```

Comment: Or, for that matter, `i=1; while (true) { if (!found) break; }` because every top item is "1", even as they pop up.

Answer (score 3):

Since you basically want to delete all rows until there are none left to delete why not rework your loop to take that into account like so:

```
string selName = "//div[@id='ctl00_MainContent_divUserInfo']//tr[contains(@class, 'item')]/td//a[@id='aDetail'][1]";
while(driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div#ctl00_MainContent_divUserInfo")).Count > 0){
    string selNameText = TextByCssSelector(selName);
    bool isNameExists = Names.Any(s => selNameText.Equals(s.Value.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

    if (isNameExists)
    {
        //if found then click on delete button to remove the item....
    }

}
```

Comment: I believe this is a much better answer than the last one.

Comment: I think it suits what the op is actually trying to do a little more as well and will account for any possible new elements showing up and such.